# Как променять шрифт просматриваемого сайта (webview)?

Tags: android, webview

Хочу изменить шрифт сайта с помощью css, просматриваю сайт через webview. Уже есть сам css:

```
.post span{font-family:Arial !important;}
```

Как его применить ?

Код webview:

```
package com.sherdle.universal.providers.web;

import com.sherdle.universal.BackPressFragment;
import com.sherdle.universal.MainActivity;
import com.sherdle.universal.R;
import com.sherdle.universal.fav.FavDbAdapter;
import com.sherdle.universal.util.Helper;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * This activity is used to display webpages
 */

public class WebviewFragment extends Fragment implements BackPressFragment {

    //Static
    public static final String HIDE_NAVIGATION = "hide_navigation";
    public static final String LOAD_DATA = "loadwithdata";

    //File upload
    public static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public static final String EXTRA_FROM_NOTIFICATION = "EXTRA_FROM_NOTIFICATION";

    private WebView mWebView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
    private String mCameraPhotoPath;

    //References
    private Activity mAct;
    private FavDbAdapter mDbHelper;

    //Layout with interaction
    private WebView browser;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    //Layouts
    private ImageButton webBackButton;
    private ImageButton webForwButton;
    private LinearLayout ll;

    //HTML5 video
    private View mCustomView;
    private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Return the existing layout if there is a savedInstance of this fragment
        if (savedInstanceState != null) { return ll; }

        ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview,
                container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        browser = (WebView) ll.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.refreshlayout);

        // settings some settings like zooming etc in seperate method for
        // suppresslint
        browserSettings();

        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            // Make sure any url clicked is opened in webview
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if ((url.contains("market://") || url.contains("mailto:")
                        || url.contains("play.google") || url.contains("tel:") || url
                        .contains("vid:")) == true) {
                    // Load new URL Don't override URL Link
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

                    return true;
                }
                // Return true to override url loading (In this case do
                // nothing).
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(browser, url);

                adjustControls();
            }

        });

        // has all to do with progress bar
        browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
                if(mFilePathCallback != null) {
                    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                    }

                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }

                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

                Intent[] intentArray;
                if(takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    if (progress == 100) {
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                } else if (progress < 100){
                    //If we do not hide the navigation, show refreshing
                    if (!WebviewFragment.this.getArguments().containsKey(HIDE_NAVIGATION)  ||
                            WebviewFragment.this.getArguments().getBoolean(HIDE_NAVIGATION) == false)
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                }
            }

            @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
            @Override
            public void onShowCustomView(View view,
                                         WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback) {
                // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
                if (mCustomView != null) {
                    onHideCustomView();
                    return;
                }

                // 1. Stash the current state
                mCustomView = view;
                mCustomView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();

                // 2. Stash the custom view callback
                mCustomViewCallback = callback;

                // 3. Add the custom view to the view hierarchy
                FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
                decor.addView(mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


                // 4. Change the state of the window
                getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
                getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onHideCustomView() {
                // 1. Remove the custom view
                FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
                decor.removeView(mCustomView);
                mCustomView = null;

                // 2. Restore the state to it's original form
                getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()
                        .setSystemUiVisibility(mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);

                //TODO Find a better solution to the keyboard not showing after custom view is hidden
                //The user will come from landscape, so we'll first 'rotate' to portrait (rotation fixes a bug of the keybaord not showing)
                getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                //The we'll restore to the detected orientation (by immediately rotating back, the user should not notice any difference and/or flickering).
                getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);

                // 3. Call the custom view callback
                mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
                mCustomViewCallback = null;


            }

        });

        browser.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        // setting an on touch listener
        browser.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                browser.reload();
            }
        });

        return ll;
    }// of oncreateview

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mAct = getActivity();

        setRetainInstance(true);

        String weburl = getArguments().getStringArray(MainActivity.FRAGMENT_DATA)[0];
        String data = getArguments().containsKey(LOAD_DATA) ? getArguments().getString(LOAD_DATA) : null;
        if (checkConnectivity() || weburl.startsWith("file:///android_asset/")) {
            //If this is the first time, load the initial url, otherwise restore the view if necessairy
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                //If we have HTML data to load, do so, else load the url.
                if (data != null) {
                    browser.loadDataWithBaseURL(weburl, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
                } else {
                    browser.loadUrl(weburl);
                }
            } else if (mCustomView != null){
                FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
                ((ViewGroup) mCustomView.getParent()).removeView(mCustomView);
                decor.addView(mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        browser.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        browser.onResume();

        if (!this.getArguments().containsKey(HIDE_NAVIGATION)  ||
                this.getArguments().getBoolean(HIDE_NAVIGATION) == false){

            ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) mAct)
                .getSupportActionBar();

            if (mAct instanceof WebviewActivity) {
                actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
            } else {
                actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
            }

            View view = mAct.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_webview_actionbar, null);
            LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.END | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            actionBar.setCustomView(view, lp);

            webBackButton = (ImageButton) mAct.findViewById(R.id.goBack);
            webForwButton = (ImageButton) mAct.findViewById(R.id.goForward);

            webBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (browser.canGoBack())
                        browser.goBack();
                }
            });
            webForwButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (browser.canGoForward())
                        browser.goForward();
                }
            });
        } else {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
        }

        adjustControls();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (!this.getArguments().containsKey(HIDE_NAVIGATION)  ||
                this.getArguments().getBoolean(HIDE_NAVIGATION) == false) {

            ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity())
                    .getSupportActionBar();

            actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
        }

    }

    /**
     * More info this method can be found at
     * http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html
     *
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.share:
            shareURL();
            return true;
        case R.id.favorite:
            mDbHelper = new FavDbAdapter(mAct);
            mDbHelper.open();

            String title = browser.getTitle();
            String url = browser.getUrl();

            if (mDbHelper.checkEvent(title, url, FavDbAdapter.KEY_WEB)) {
                // This item is new
                mDbHelper.addFavorite(title, url, FavDbAdapter.KEY_WEB);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mAct,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.favorite_success),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mAct,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.favorite_duplicate),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.webview_menu, menu);
    }

    // Checking for an internet connection
    private boolean checkConnectivity() {
        boolean enabled = true;

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) mAct
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if ((info == null || !info.isConnected() || !info.isAvailable())) {
            enabled = false;

            Helper.noConnection(mAct);
        }

        return enabled;
    }

    public void adjustControls() {
        webBackButton = (ImageButton) mAct.findViewById(R.id.goBack);
        webForwButton = (ImageButton) mAct.findViewById(R.id.goForward);

        if (webBackButton == null || webForwButton == null) return;

        if (browser.canGoBack()) {
            webBackButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        } else {
            webBackButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        }
        if (browser.canGoForward()) {
            webForwButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        } else {
            webForwButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        }
    }

    // sharing
    private void shareURL() {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        String appname = getString(R.string.app_name);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                (getResources().getString(R.string.web_share_begin)) + appname
                        + getResources().getString(R.string.web_share_end)
                        + browser.getUrl());
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources()
                .getString(R.string.share)));
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void browserSettings() {
        // set javascript and zoom and some other settings
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        browser.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        browser.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        // enable all plugins (flash)
        browser.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleBackPress() {
        if (browser.canGoBack()){
            browser.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // Check that the response is a good one
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if(mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `onPageFinished` пропишите:

```
String js = "javascript:(function(){var newStyle=document.createElement('style'); newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(\"@font-face{font-family:'sans-serif-thin';\")); document.head.appendChild(newStyle); document.body.style.fontFamily = \"sans-serif-thin\";})()";
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    view.evaluateJavascript(js, new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {
        }
    });
} else {
    view.loadUrl(js);
}
```

После загрузки страницы шрифт поменяется на нужный.

P.S. Замените `sans-serif-thin` на нужный

---

UPD. Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получается после строки "super.onPageFinished(browser, url);" вставить ваш код?

Comment: @user210886 , да

Comment: Вот я вставил, заменил sans-serif-thin  на  Arial, но текст на сайте не изменился

Comment: @user210886 добавил пример результата. Если не меняется, значит нет такого шрифта. Нужно добавить его в assets и подключить.

Comment: для примера решил воспользоваться уже подключенным roboto-light, но опять текст не поменялся, может что то не так? http://pastebin.com/amGbWN26

Comment: @user210886 гляньте, к примеру, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android . Необходимо указать "sans-serif-light" для roboto light. Еще по шрифтам гляньте: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/data/fonts/fonts.xml

Comment: спасибо, текст стал меняться. Но вот на форуме, если текст имеет не стандартный шрифт, не меняет. [font='comic sans ms', cursive][size=5][color=#008000]t3стированiе [/color][/size][/font] вот допустим текст представляется так и приложение его не меняет

Answer (score 0):

подключается стандартной разметкой в HTML файле. WebView это браузер как бы...